How to ask Plasmo to throw typescript errors during build?
I created a new Plasmo project (https://github.com/PlasmoHQ/plasmo). pnpm create plasmo example-dir
I opened popup.tsx and added the simple line let a: number = "just a string";
I ran pnpm dev
I expect an error in the console TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
But the only thing I see is that the build succeeded.
What am I doing wrong and how do I ask Plasmo to throw TS errors during build into the console?
